# Document methods inside an object that is a property of the class in better-docs

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuex, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have a Vuex module factory that, has some default mutations and actions. I'd like to document these using better-docs which uses JSDoc syntax. However, I am stuck on documenting methods that are in mutations object that is a property of CustomModule class.

I tried using [this](https://jsdoc.app/tags-memberof.html) way, however, it didn't work for me.

This is the example code

```js
/**
 *
 * A generic class to create custom Vuex module
 * @export
 * @abstract
 * @class CustomModule
 * @category Generic Store
 * @template Entity Entity used in state
 * @property {Repository} repository Generic class for handling requests
 * @property {object} mutations Contains all Vuex mutations
 */
export abstract class CustomModule<Entity extends EntityBasee> = {}> {

  /**
   * Mutations
   * @memberof CustomModule
   * @alias Mutations
   */
  mutations = {
    // I want to document these methods to be something like that CustomModule.mutations.assignItems
    assignItems: (state: ModuleState<Entity>, value: Entity[]) => {
      state.items = value;
    },
    selectItem: (state: ModuleState<Entity>, value: Entity) => {
      state.selectedItem = value;
    },
    setIsLoading: (state: ModuleState<Entity>, value: boolean) => {
      state.isLoading = value;
    },
    setError: (state: ModuleState<Entity>, value: string) => {
      state.error = value;
    }
  };
}
```